# Elastic search logstash conf error while publish

Tags: logstash-configuration, logstash-file

While validating the logstash conf file, result is ok.
But when i try to publish the logstash there is error which i can't able to resolve it.

[image]

Let me know anyone has any clue on this error.

Comment: Could you please provide the full path of logstash_new.conf file ? and try to run it again.

Comment: Other way, Could you also please check in the output section your logstash.conf file that the hostIP and port of the elasticsearch is correct or not ? If that is correct, please share the logstash.conf file here so as to dig a little deeper. :)

Comment: Hi Saurav, Thanks for the comments. i have resolved the error by correcting the host path and re-execute the logstash file and compilation was successful.